# Access variable from scope of another function?

Tags: php, scope

```
<?php
  function foo($one, $two){
    bar($one);
  }

  function bar($one){
    echo $one;
    //How do I access $two from the parent function scope?
  }
?>
```

If I have the code above, how can I access the variable $two from within bar(), **without** passing it in as a variable (for reasons unknown).

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: short answer: you don't.

Comment: The whole point of defining a variable within a particular scope is to limit access so that it's **not** accessible outside of that scope. So no, it's not possible. If you want to do this, then don't define it in local scope - use a class or global scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a class - you can declare $two as an instance field which will be accessible to all instance methods:

```
class Blah {
  private $two;
  public function foo($one, $two){
    this->$two = $two;
    bar($one);
  }

  public function bar($one){
    echo $one;
    // How do I access $two from the parent function scope?
    this->$two;
  }
}
```

Comment: While your answer didn't exactly answer the question (I'm still curious if it's possible outside of using a class), it DID remind me I was already inside a class, so I just made it a class member.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A crude way is to export it into global scope, for example:

```
<?php
  function foo($one, $two){
    global $g_two;
    $g_two = $two;
    bar($one);
  }

  function bar($one){
    global $g_two;
    echo $g_two;
    echo $one;
    //How do I access $two from the parent function scope?
  }
?>
```

Comment: The snag is that you have to define a global variable in global scope. So you cannot define it inside a function and then "export" it to global without having defined it in global before entering the function's scope. In your case that would be:
<?php
$g_two = null;

  function foo($one, $two){
    global $g_two;
  ...

?>

Comment: This answer was like 12 years ago, so ...

Comment: So? 12 years are not a very long time and google hasn't forgotten it and I was just trying to help subsequent searchers, not criticising you.

Answer (score 0):

I do use $global to access variables in my entire script.

Like this:

```
public function exist($id) {
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM web_users_session where user_id='$id'";
    return $this->_check = $db->num_req($query);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at another answers? You repeat them and also didn't use code for 2 functions