# Can I share variables between different functions in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, function

I'll try to explain with an example...

Let's say I have two different functions, and one of them has a defined variable. In the second function, I don't wanna write the same variable again, can I simply use the variable from the first function in the second one WITHOUT redefining it in the second function?

Something like:

```
function a()
{
  $var = "my variable";
}

function b()
{
 echo $var;
}
```

Sorry if this questions is a bit silly, but I'm still a beginner =).

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` for a selection.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai (but really @user445820): One can also highlight (select) the code and then click the button with all of the 0s and 1s.

Comment: +1 Clearly stated, valid beginner's question. Thanks for including an illustrative code sample.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access variable from scope of another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699117/access-variable-from-scope-of-another-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can do globals, but of PHP 5.3.0+ has **[anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)**, so you can also do closures:

```
<?php

function a(){
  $a = 1;  
  echo "First: $a, ";
  ++$a;

    // This is a closure. It can gain access to the variables of a() with the 
    // use option.
  $b = function() use ($a) {
      echo "second: $a";  
  };  
  $b();
};
a(); // Outputs: First: 1, second: 2
?>
```

### **[Try it out at this Codepad example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uUhgZg)**

or probably more useful:

```
<?php

function a(){
  $a = 1;  
  echo "First: $a, ";
  ++$a;
  $b = function() use ($a) {
      echo "second: $a";  
  };        
  return $b;
};
$fun = a();     // $fun is now $b & $b has access to $a!
$fun();
// Outputs: First: 1, second: 2
?>
```

### **[Try it out at this Codepad example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rIWZJ6)**

From the docs:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header. Inheriting variables from the parent scope is not the same as using global variables. Global variables exist in the global scope, which is the same no matter what function is executing. The parent scope of a closure is the function in which the closure was declared (not necessarily the function it was called from).

Comment: Interesting typo consistency ("fist" instead of "first", both times).

Comment: @user359996 - Thanks. Copy paste will do that ;)

Answer (score 16):

The cleanest solution here is to make A and B methods of a class and have the common variables as private static variables.  This removes the messiness of globals and allows both functions to be globally accessible.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static $a = 1;

    public static function a() {
        self::$a = 2;
    }

    public static function b() {
        echo self::$a;
    }
}
```

You can then call the functions:

```
SomeClass::a();
SomeClass::b();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$a = 1;
function a(){
  global $a;
  $a = 2;
  }
function b(){
  global $a;
  echo $a;
  }

a();
b();
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: The asker is clearly an extreme neophyte if they don't know about global variables yet. Some explanatory text would be instructive.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but it gives you global variables.  Global variables are the bane of maintainable software, and all programmers, especially PHP programmers, would do well to not use them.

Comment: What if places of the functions are different, let's imagine function b() is first and then after it comes function a(), does this one still apply?

Answer (score 5):

Like this . you can use

```
function a()
{
  global $var; 
  $var = "my variable";
}

function b()
{
 global $var; 
 echo $var;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this. This is a more common implementation. Remember that functions can be passed parameters and can return values.

```
// Main
$a = a();
b($a);

function a()
{
  return "my variable";
}

function b($a)
{
 echo $a;
}
```

You have the main body of a program, and the variable `$a` remains in scope there. Globals are rarely used, and technically never needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

class A
{
    private $p;
    private $q;
    private $ans;
    public  function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello PratikPatel";
    }
    public function getdata($a,$b)
    {

        $this->p=$a;
        $this->q=$b;
        $ans=$this ->p/$this->q;
        $this->ans=$ans;

    }
    public function div1()
    {
        echo "your division answer is:=".$this->ans."<br/>";
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello "."<br/>";
    }

}

$p=new B();
$p1=new B();
$p2=new B();
$p -> getdata(20,10);
echo $p1 -> hello();
$p2 -> div1();
```

?>

**this code in problem that can not a print a division result**

Comment: Besides the code, it is important to understand you solution - please elaborate. Also, it is not clear what you were trying to say in your last sentence