# Create a variable in one function and pass it to another in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

Let me first say I've spent a day reading three google pages of articles on this subject, as well as studied this page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898170/can-i-share-variables-between-different-functions-in-php).

Ok, here's my dilemma. I have two functions. Both called upon via AJAX. This first one assigns a value to the variable and the second one uses that variable. Both functions are triggered by two separate buttons and need to stay that way. The AJAX and the firing off of the functions work fine, but the variable isn't passed. Here is my code:

```
if( $_REQUEST["subjectLine"] ) //initiate first function
{
    $CID = wpCreateChimpCampaign();
    echo $CID; //this works
}

if( $_REQUEST["testEmails"] ) //initiate second function
{
    echo $CID; //does not return anything but should contain "apple"
    wpSendChimpTest($CID);
} 


function wpCreateChimpCampaign () //first function
{
    $CID = "apple";
    return $CID;    
}

function wpSendChimpTest ($CID) //second function
{
    echo $CID; //does not return anything but should contain "apple"
}
```

I'm open to using a class but I haven't had much luck there either. I was hoping to solve this issue without using classes. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making 2 separate calls to this file, it may be helpful for you to visualise this as being 2 functions in 2 totally separate files. Although they exist in the same PHP file, because they used called in different calls, they don't retain the value of the variable $CID. Once the file has run, the variable is destroyed and when you call the file again, the value is null again.

So you need to store that variable between calls. You can either store it in a database or store it in a session variable.

So call session_start(); at the beginning of the file, then rather than use $CID, just use $_SESSION['CID'];

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the hold up is. The code you have will work:

```
$CID = wpCreateChimpCampaign(); // returns 'apple'
wpSendChimpTest($CID);          // echos 'apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, but are you certain that all requirements are being met so both functions execute?

In other words are you supplying values for both `$_REQUEST["subjectLine"]` and `$_REQUEST["testEmails"]`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure both of them work. I set up an example [here](http://www.yorkvilledesigns.com/mailchimp/api/stackoverflow.php).

Comment: Ok, I think @user2044709 has hit on the problem - each time you call one of your functions, it is a new ajax request and the context is reset. If you nest your function calls, the functions will retain the same context and it should work, but it does mean you will effectively have to call both functions every time.