# how to use variables from one submit button by another submit button inside same form in php

Tags: php, html, function, variables

In my php code, there is a form with multiple submit buttons inside and the variable of 1st form is allocated the value after clicking the submit button and similar for the second form by **$_POST[]**. Here I want to use the value of the the first submission inside the second .

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
global $name;

          //BLOCK1
    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Register Yourself") 
        {
        global $name;           
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo $name;
    };
         // BLOCK 2

    if($_POST['formSubmit1'] == "Register Yourself1") 
        {
        global $name;           
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo $id;
            echo $name;   // I want to print "$name" here

    };

?>
<html>
<title>form</title>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <b> <label for='name'>Name: </label> </b>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" value="<?=$name;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Register Yourself" />
<br/><br/>
<b> <label for='id'> id: </label> </b>
    <input type="text" name="id" maxlength="50" value="<?=$id;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit1" value="Register Yourself1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the concept given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898170/can-i-share-variables-between-different-functions-in-php).
In the above program, I have declared the variable **$name** as global both inside and outside, to use in the second one.

Please try to find the error so that I can print inside the second block...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to declare it inside and outside, they are if tests not functions. You don't need to use a global at all.

Comment: I am not getting ur point.... please clarify

Comment: You need to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Hi Pitchinnate, bethadele's sol worked for me... thanks for your suggestion....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pitchinnate explained the correct answer, but if you're new to PHP, you might not understand the comment.

The link you referenced was asking about how to share variables between functions. Your code in the sample above is not using functions; it's using "if" conditions.

If your code isn't working, it's more related to your use of the $_POST array. When the user submits the form, it doesn't matter which button they click; the $_POST array will contain all the data from the various inputs in that form. So you might have more success with something like this:

```
// let's set up the empty variables for clarity's sake
$name = '';
$id = '';

// now check if the $_POST array has stuff in it
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo '<p>' . $name . '</p>';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo '<p>' . $id . '</p>';
    }
};

<form action="" method="post">
    <b> <label for='name'>Name: </label> </b>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" value="<?=$name;?>" />
    <br/><br/>
    <b><label for='id'> id: </label> </b>
    <input type="text" name="id" maxlength="50" value="<?=$id;?>" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Register Yourself" />
</form>
```

You really only need one submit button. When the user clicks that button, the form will get submitted to the server and the server will put the values from the input fields into the $_POST array.

Also, if the want the form to submit to itself, all you have to do is specify **action=""** and the server will assume you're resubmitting to the current page.

Comment: Yes bethadele, I am very new to PHP programming, I understood your solution ... but I want to use a DB query using values of both $id and $name, so can you please explain me what to do for that... Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Hi bethadele, I had few doubts in my original program those are cleared from your solution ... Its  Working now :) thnks

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking, that the below value is not correct, if you are not getting the value you want.

```
     if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Register Yourself") 

 if($_POST['formSubmit1'] == "Register Yourself1")
```

So, I would advice you to try this code:

```
 if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Register Yourself") 
        {

  echo $_POST['name'];
    }else{
        echo 'formSubmit = '.$_POST['formSubmit'];
    }
         // BLOCK 2

    if($_POST['formSubmit1'] == "Register Yourself1") 
        {
  echo $_POST['id'].'<Br/>';
  echo $_POST['name'].'<Br/>';


    }else{
        echo 'formSubmit1 = '.$_POST['formSubmit'];
```

It will tell if you POST is not matching the value