# Access data from global scope from inside function scope

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, parameter-passing

I want to get random number and passing it between functions. I tried to tag `$randId` in `user_edit.php?session=` but when I tag the same variable `$randId` into `user_add.php?session=`, I cannot get the same random number; I just get nothing.

I need a way of passing the same random number value between functions into `user_add.php?session=`

```
function get_user_edit_link() {
    $url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $x = pathinfo($url);

    $MIN_SESSION_ID = 1000000000;
    $MAX_SESSION_ID = 9999999999;
    $randId = mt_rand($MIN_SESSION_ID, $MAX_SESSION_ID);
    $randId = mt_rand($MIN_SESSION_ID, $MAX_SESSION_ID);

    return $ee = $x['dirname'] . 'user_edit.php?session='. $randId;
}

function get_user_add_link() {
    $url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $x = pathinfo($url);
    return $ee = $x['dirname'] . 'user_add.php?session='. $randId;
}
```

Comment: Please add in your question the code you call `get_user_edit_link()` and `get_user_add_link()`

Comment: You've got some fundamental misunderstanding here, you should do a little reading on "PHP variable scope" to better understand this.

Comment: `user_add.php` and `user_edit.php` are not functions; they're URL end-points (or pages if you prefer) and, in this case, also files. `get_user_edit_link()` and `get_user_add_link()` are functions. Also, be aware that PHP has a feature to transmit information between pages that's called "sessions" (it isn't wrong to name a URL parameter `session` but it can be confusing).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to create global variable and access it in each function. For example -

```
$MIN_SESSION_ID = 1000000000;
$MAX_SESSION_ID = 9999999999;
$randId = mt_rand($MIN_SESSION_ID, $MAX_SESSION_ID);

function get_user_edit_link() {
    global $randId;
}
```

this way it becomes accessible in both functions, allowing you to share the same random number between them.

Comment: @apexanchor Just keep in mind there are some drawback of using a global var make sure to read about it since it can introduce some problems later

Comment: @apexanchor glad i could help but consider this as a temporary solution

Comment: Why not have regular function arguments? Variables popping up from nowhere (and changing randomly in unexpected/unknown locations) are a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes i am aware of those nightmares which is why i added the caution. Also i can imagine certain use cases for example singleton pattern or resource management. We may not see them so often is due to usage of frameworks which gives us so many things easily at our disposal. In this question's case, the use case i believe is caching to achieve global caching mechanism of session, if i am not wrong, which in case of frameworks is built in right.

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score -1):

Using global variables is generally considered bad practice. Better to pass the values into the functions that need them as an argument:

```
<?php 

// declare functions.
function get_user_edit_link($randId) {
        $url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $x = pathinfo($url);
        return $ee = $x['dirname'] . 'user_edit.php?session='. $randId;
}

function get_user_add_link($randId) {
        $url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $x = pathinfo($url);
        return $ee = $x['dirname'] . 'user_add.php?session='. $randId;
}

// Create random ID
$MIN_SESSION_ID = 1000000000;
$MAX_SESSION_ID = 9999999999;
$randId = mt_rand($MIN_SESSION_ID, $MAX_SESSION_ID);

// Call your functions

$link = get_user_add_link($randId);
// or
$link = get_user_edit_link($randId);
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: @mickmackusa completely agree but can you please edit the duplicate to be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898170/can-i-share-variables-between-different-functions-in-php). I believe it's more specifically related to the question asked here