# how to access variable of a method

Tags: php

I have this class and I want to get the values in second method `runSecond` from `Gettest` method. How would I do that?

```
 class Test {
    public static function Gettest($x, $y, $z){
        $x = $x;
        $x = $x . basename($y);

        self::runSecond();  
    }

    private function runSecond(){
        //how do I access $x here? I need to know the value of $x, $y and $z here 
        // and I dont want to pass it like this  self::runSecond($x, $y, $z)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Seriously. Don't. Stop. Ask yourself what you want. Then do it a sane way. (I would recommend just passing in the value to `runSecond`, but a class *member variable* -- see [Classes And Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) -- is another approach that may be appropriate -- but looks doubtful from this limited context.)

Comment: I want to learn how to access class memeber variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access variable from scope of another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699117/access-variable-from-scope-of-another-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you not want to pass the values into your second method?

Method parameters are the accepted way of doing this.

The only other option you have is to use global or member variables, but for something like this I would highly suggest parameters instead.  There is no good reason I can see not to.

If you really, absolutely, have to do this (and I still don't see why), you can use a private member variable like this:

```
class Test {
    private $x;
    private $y;
    private $z;

    public static function Gettest($x, $y, $z){
        $x = $x;
        $x = $x . basename($y);

        $test = new Test();
        $test->x = $x;
        $test->y = $y;
        $test->z = $z;

        $test->runSecond();  
    }

    private function runSecond(){
        $this->x;
        $this->y;
        $this->z;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to create an instance of the class to call the second method.  Your original way of using `self::` would not work to call a non static method, even if you did pass the values as parameters.

Comment: I want to know how to access the variable in the memebers?

Comment: I fixed the problem.  To use a member variable, you need to use `$this->` which refers to the current object, not `self::` which refers to the class.  I still don't see why you don't want to just use parameters.

Comment: If you want help you are going to need to tell us what the error you are getting is.  It doesn't work isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: If calling `Test::Gettest()`, there will be a fatal error for trying to use `$this` in a static context.

Comment: I updated the example, your original code wouldn't have worked anyways since you were trying to call a non static method from `self::`.