# Pass variable value between php functions

Tags: php, function, php-5.3

I'm trying to share a value of `$shippingMethod` from the `getMainDetails()` function to the `estimateDeliveryDate()` function in the same class to run a conditional but the second function doesn't appear to be getting the value:

```
private function getMainDetails($order)
{
    //This value is correctly being set from my order details in Magento
    $shippingMethod = strtolower($order->getShippingDescription());
}

private function estimateDeliveryDate($orderCreatedDate)
{
    if ($shippingMethod == 'saturday delivery') {
        echo 'Saturday Delivery';
    } else {
        echo 'Standard Delivery';
    } 
}
```

Wondered if someone could help?

Thank you.

Comment: The best way is probably to have `getMainDetails(...)` return `$shippingMethod`, and then pass it as an argument to `estimateDeliveryDate(...)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php  There you'll find all you need for that. Let me know if you need some more help

Comment: The problem is that your `estimateDeliverDate` method doesn't define the `$shippingMethod` variable.  If you save it to the object, other methods can use it. `$this->shippingMethod = strotolower(...);`, then inside your other functions do `$this->shippingMethod == 'saturday delivery'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699124/8188398  That would be your solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access variable from scope of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699117/access-variable-from-scope-of-another-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your variable as a property, like so:

```
class myClass
{
    private $shippingMethod;

    private function getMainDetails($order)
    {
        //This value is correctly being set from my order details in Magento
        $this->shippingMethod = strtolower($order->getShippingDescription());
    }


    private function estimateDeliveryDate($orderCreatedDate)
    {
        if ($this->shippingMethod == 'saturday delivery')
        {
            echo 'Saturday Delivery';
        } else {
            echo 'Standard Delivery';
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

However, a more solid approach at this would be something along these lines:

```
class DeliveryHandler
{
    private $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    private function getDeliveryDateEstimate()
    {
        if ($this->order->getShippingMethod() == 'saturday delivery') {
            return 'Saturday Delivery';
        } else {
            return 'Standard Delivery';
        }

    }
}

class Order
{
    public function getShippingMethod()
    {
        return strtolower($this->getShippingDescription());
    }
}
```

Few of things going on in that example.

1. I moved `shippingMethod()` into the `Order` class as it is not the `DeliveryHandler`s responsibility so it should not have to care about what's going on in that method. The data belongs to and comes from `Order`.
2. I made `getDeliveryDateEstimate()` return a string instead of using `echo`. This makes your code more reusable - eg what if one day you want to pass this to a template or another variable instead of echoing it. This way you keep your options open.
3. I'm using dependency injection to pass the `Order` class into the `DeliveryHandler`, thus making the public interface of `Order` available to `DeliveryHandler`.

If you happen to have a laracast subscription you could check out these courses here, they explain all this stuff in a nice digestible format:

https://laracasts.com/series/object-oriented-bootcamp-in-php

https://laracasts.com/series/solid-principles-in-php

Comment: A function that's called `get...` but doesn't `return` anything and instead *sets* a property is severely misnamed and/or misguided.

Comment: true @deceze but I didn't choose these names, I merely copied the author's code

Comment: @deceze There is a lot more code in the functions that sets/gets but I didn't want to paste all of that here as i didn't feel it was relevant.

Comment: @doubleplusgood - I extended my answer to highlight how you could implement this in a more oop friendly fashion

Answer (score 2):

Use properties of the class (`$this->variable`), instead of local variables (`$variable`). You also have a syntax error in your code, where you compare for the value of `$shippingMethod`.

The method below assumes that you call `getMainDetails()` *before*  being able to use `estimateDeliveryDate()`. You should however ensure that, by having `$order` being passed to `estimateDeliveryDate()`, and call `getMainDetails()` from there (where you `return` from the getter instead of set a property).

```
class Foo (
    private $this->shippingMethod; // Initialize

    /* Your other methods */

    private function getMainDetails($order)
    {
        //This value is correctly being set from my order details in Magento
        $this->shippingMethod = strtolower($order->getShippingDescription());
    }

    private function estimateDeliveryDate($orderCreatedDate)
    {
        if ($this->shippingMethod == 'saturday delivery') {
            echo 'Saturday Delivery';
        } else {
            echo 'Standard Delivery';
        }
    }
)
```

- [PHP.net on properties of classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Alternatively, you can `return` from each function - which is what you **should** do from methods that is  a "getter", i.e. `getMainDetails()`

Comment: Yes, but... how do you ensure that `getMainDetails` is called before `estimateDeliveryDate` is, i.e. that the state is consistent?